# Loop crashing in C

Tags: c, do-while

I'm very new to C and I'm still learning the basics. I'm creating an application that reads in a text file and breaks down the words individually. My intention will be to count the amount of times each word occurs.

Anyway, the last do-while loop in the code below executes fine, and then crashes. This loop prints memory address to this word (pointer) and then prints the word. It accomplishes this fine, and then crashes on the last iteration. My intention is to push this memory address into a singly linked list, albeit once it's stopped crashing.

Also, just a quick mention regarding the array sizes below; I yet figured out how to set the correct size needed to hold the word character array etc because you must define the size before the array is filled, and I don't know how to do this. Hence why I've set them to 1024.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE * pFile;
    int c;
    int n = 0;
    char *wp;
    char wordArray[1024];
    char delims[] = " "; // delims spaces in the word array.
    char *result = NULL;
            result = strtok(wordArray, delims);
    char holder[1024];

    pFile=fopen (argv[1],"r");
    if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
    else {
            do {
                c = fgetc (pFile);
                wordArray[n] = c;
                n++;
            } while (c != EOF);
            n = 0;
            fclose (pFile);

            do {
                result = strtok(NULL, delims);
                holder[n] = *result; // holder stores the value of 'result', which should be a word.
                wp = &holder[n]; // wp points to the address of 'holder' which holds the 'result'.
                n++;
                printf("Pointer value = %d\n", wp); // Prints the address of holder.
                printf("Result is \"%s\"\n", result); // Prints the 'result' which is a word from the array.
                //sl_push_front(&wp); // Push address onto stack.
            } while (result != NULL);
    }       
    return 0;
```

}

Please ignore the bad program structure, as I mentioned, I'm new to this!

Thanks

Comment: First, this: `holder[n] = *result;` is likely *not* doing what you think it is. Second, what do you suppose that does when `strtok(NULL, delims)` returns NULL due to end-of-tokens condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your second loop attempts to dereference `result` *before* you check for it being `NULL`.  Restructure your code as follows:

```
result = strtok( wordArray, delims ); // do this *after* you have read data into
                                      // wordArray
while( result != NULL )
{
  holder[n] = *result; 
  ...
  result = strtok( NULL, delims );
}
```

Although...

You're attempting to read the entire contents of the file into memory before breaking it up into words; that's not going to work for files bigger than the size of your buffer (currently 1K).  If I may make a suggestion, change your code such that you're reading individual words as you go.  Here's an example that breaks the input stream up into words delimited by whitespace (blanks, newlines, tabs, etc.) and punctuation (period, comma, etc.):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buffer[1024];
  int c;
  size_t n = 0;

  FILE *input = stdin;

  if( argc > 1 )
  {
    input = fopen( argv[1], "r");
    if (!input)
      input = stdin;
  }

  while(( c = fgetc(input)) != EOF )
  {
    if (isspace(c) || ispunct(c))
    {
      if (n > 0)
      {
        buffer[n] = 0;
        printf("read word %s\n", buffer);
        n = 0;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      buffer[n++] = c;
    }
  }
  if (n > 0)
  {
    buffer[n] = 0;
    printf("read word %s\n", buffer);
  }
  fclose(input);
  return 0;
}
```

No warranties express or implied (having pounded this out before 7:00 a.m.).  But it should give you a flavor of how to parse a file as you go.  If nothing else, it avoids using `strtok`, which is *not* the greatest of tools for parsing input.  You should be able to adapt this general structure to your code. For best results, you should abstract that out into its own function:

```
int getNextWord(FILE *stream, char *buf, size_t bufsize)
{
  int c;
  size_t n = 0;

  while(( c = fgetc(input)) != EOF && n < bufsize)
  {
    if (isspace(c) || ispunct(c))
    {
      if (n > 0)
      {
        buf[n] = 0;
        n = 0;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      buffer[n++] = c;
    }
  }
  if (n > 0)
  {
    buffer[n] = 0;
    printf("read word %s\n", buffer);
  }

  if (n == 0)
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
}
```

and you would call it like

```
void foo(void)
{
  char word[SOME_SIZE];
  ...
  while (getNextWord(inFile, word, sizeof word))
  {
    do_something_with(word);
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It has been an extremely helpful comment!

Answer (score 1):

If you expect in your `do...while` code, that `result` could be `null` (this is the condition for loop break), how do you think this code-line:

`holder[n] = *result;`

must work? It seems to me, that it is the reason for crashing in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Change `do while` loop to `while`

use

```
while (condition)
{
}
```

instead of

```
do {
}while(condition)
```

It is crashing because you are trying to derefrance a NULL pointer `result` in do while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I work mostly with Objective-C and was just looking at your question for fun, but I may have a solution.

Before setting `n=0;` after your first do-while loop, create another variable called `totalWords` and set it equal to n, totalWords can be declared anywhere within the file (except within one of the do-while loops), but can be defined at the top to the else block since its lifetime is short:

```
totalWords = n;
```

then you can set n back to zero:

```
n = 0;
```

Your conditional for the final do-while loop should then say:

```
...
} while (n <= ++totalWords);
```

The logic behind the application will thus say, count the words in the file (there are n words, which is the totalWords in the file). When program prints the results to the console, it will run the second do-while loop, which will run until n is one result past the value of totalWords (this ensures that you print the final word).

Alternately, it is better practice and clearer for other programmers to use a loop and a half:

```
do {
result = strtok(NULL, delims);
holder[n] = *result;
wp = &holder[n];
printf("Pointer value = %d\n", wp);
printf("Result is \"%s\"\n", result);
//sl_push_front(&wp); // Push address onto stack.
if (n == totalWords) break; // This forces the program to exit the do-while after we have printed the last word
n++; // We only need to increment if we have not reached the last word
// if our logic is bad, we will enter an infinite loop, which will tell us while testing that our logic is bad.
} while (true);
```